# existence of a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ with special propert about outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

prove that there is a nonmeasurable set called $E$ that

$E \subset I=[0,1]$ &:

$1/2 < m^*(I-E)<m^*(E)<1$

i think may be vitali set could help,but i'm not sure.

is there any hint?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a (non-measurable) set $A\subset[0,3/10]$ such that $m^*(A) = 3/10$ and $m^*([0,3/10]\setminus A) = 3/10$ (such a set exists, see Theorem 3.4.4 in [Dudley:RAP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521007542)). For $\varepsilon >0$ small define $B = A\cup(3/10,3/10+\varepsilon]\cup[6/10,1]$. Then 
$$m^*(B) \geq m^*(A\cup[6/10,1]) = 7/10$$
because $dist(A,[6/10,1])>0$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Outer_measure_and_topology). For its complement, 
$$ m^*([0,1]\setminus B) = m^*(([3/10]\setminus A)\cup(3/10+\varepsilon,6/10)) = 6/10-\varepsilon > 1/2  $$
for the same reason.